# Why are local functions not possible in ES6 classes?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What was the idea about leaving out something like this in ES6:

```
class Foo {
   myMethod(){
      // do something with 'bar'
   }
   constructor(){
       this.myMethod();
   }
   otherMethod(){
       this.myMethod();
   }
}
```

I know that it's possible to define the function in the constructor or outside the class and then use it with `myMethod()`. However coming from other languages I was surprised to see classes, but no local (or private) methods. I couldn't find anything on the internet about the reason why this was left out.

Comment: > coming from other languages I was surprised to see classes   

EcmaScript doesn't have classes per say. If you're coming from another language, you should read up on prototypes. ES6 classes are mostly just syntax sugar.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have private properties/methods, and the class syntax is merely sugar for prototypal inheritance.

Comment: @comments: Ok, so they're not "real classes". Thank you.

Comment: You could use TypeScript, which has private and protected stuff (just compile-time checks though).

Comment: it's because of the reference-based security model of JS: there is no function ownership, since everything is dynamic (and call/apply/bind able). Therefore, the only way to privacy is to hide references, and if said refs were sitting in the class, anyone could reach them. Adding traditional privates would require bolting on a lot of call-time checking; slow and not needed since _protected_ methods/getters/setters  can offer privacy.

Comment: This might be a worthwhile read for you: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Comment: Encapsulation as a benefit of OOP failed anyway.

Comment: "*leaving out something like this in ES6*" - like what? The example you've given works. What do you mean? And what does 'bar' refer to?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
I just realized your post was about functions, not variables. Since functions are a type of variable, all these solutions work for function even though I didn't explicitly make the examples functions

---

I have found several solutions, each of which have their pros and cons:

#### Method 0: Factories

```
var Foo = (function() {
  let priv = {
    "eh": 0
  };
  return class Foo {
    constructor(num) {
      priv.eh = num;
    }
    test() {
      return priv.eh;
    }
  };
})();

var a = new Foo(383);

console.log(a.test());
```

Taking advantage of JS scoping to hide a variable, `priv` behind a function

Pros:

- Perfectly secure. It's basically impossible to access priv unless you return a pointer of it
- Takes advantage of a well-used javascript paradigm. Factories have been used by programmers for year

  - Private variables do not clash with parent class(es)

Cons:

- It's not very clear or readable

---

#### Method 1: Define everything from the constructor

```
class Foo2 {
  constructor(num) {
    Object.assign(this, {
      test() {
        return num;
      }
    });
  }
}

var b = new Foo2(262);

console.log(b.test());
```

Just what it says on the box.

Pros:

- Perfectly secure again. There's no way to access local variable from outside the scope
- Little more readable than Method 1. It's somewhat obvious what everything does
- Private variables do not clash with parent class(es)

Cons:

- Clogs the constructor function
- Still not very readable

---

#### Method 2: Naming Convention

```
class Foo3 {
  constructor(num) {
    this._eh = num;
  }
  test() {
    return this._eh;
  }
}

var c = new Foo3(101);

console.log(c.test());
```

No need to hide behind strange security procedures. Just specify in the name which properties are "private"

Pros:

- Very easy to read, can take advantage of class structure

Cons:

- Offers absolutely no protection, only a recommendation.
- Private variables clash with the private variables of parent classes

  ---

#### Method 3: Symbols

```
const eh = Symbol("eh");

class Foo4 {
  constructor(num) {
    this[eh] = num;
  }
  test() {
    return this[eh];
  }
}

var d = new Foo4(100);

console.log(d.test());
```

I just wanted to include this one because I thought it was cool

Pros:

- Readable as naming convention. Private variables don't get strings, they get Symbols. Very easy to read

Cons:

- Pointless. In any situation where the parent scope is protected, you can just store private variables there

  - Not secure. Even if you solve the problem above, people can access all keys (including Symbols) with `Reflect.ownKeys()`

Hope this was helpful!